# What's the difference between Timer and Thread? Python, threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

What's the difference between `threading.Timer` and `threading.Thread`?

When I use the Timer function, it starts target command in separate thread with delay.

When I use the Thread function, it starts target command with args in separate thread.

It's the same, I think, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth looking at the implementation.

```
# _Timer is thinly wrapped by Timer; excluding that wrapper for terseness
class _Timer(Thread):
    """Call a function after a specified number of seconds:

            t = Timer(30.0, f, args=[], kwargs={})
            t.start()
            t.cancel()     # stop the timer's action if it's still waiting

    """

    def __init__(self, interval, function, args=[], kwargs={}):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.interval = interval
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.finished = Event()

    def cancel(self):
        """Stop the timer if it hasn't finished yet"""
        self.finished.set()

    def run(self):
        self.finished.wait(self.interval)
        if not self.finished.is_set():
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        self.finished.set()
```

Thus, yes, a Timer is just an instance of Thread that invokes your function after a given delay, using the [Event](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects) mechanism for efficient scheduling and providing a `cancel()` that reliably prevents the function from being called at all if the delay has not yet expired.

---

As we see above, `Thread` is the implementation that does the heavy lifting, and `Timer` is a helper that adds extra functionality (a delay at the front); `Timer(0, func)` wouldn't work if `Thread` didn't exist.

A `Thread` being an object gives more flexibility than being *only* able to override the function to be called, without having that function having access to instance variables -- look at `Timer` itself, and how it uses that capability to add and respect `cancel()`. You can't do that on top of `Timer` without subclassing `_Timer`, which (as the name implies) is an implementation detail not promised to be stable in future releases.

Thus, `Timer()` has more moving parts and is less flexible than `Thread()` -- both of those being innate disadvantages in software engineering -- but is handy for a specific moderately-common use case. Why would one *not* provide both?

Answer (score 1):

You already explained the difference.  `Thread` is a thread, `Timer` is a thread whose execution is deferred for at least a specified time.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects

Comment: Well, `Timer` extends thread, so thread implements threading, and timer implements the delay on top.  So technically all threads could be Timer with 0 delay.  But it makes more sense in code to add functionality as a sublass; there's no benefit in "minimizing classes"

Comment: @CharlesDuff, but I can just use 'Timer(0, func)'. I thought this is not pythonic way...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thank you, now I understand.

Comment: ...moved my end of the discussion here into my answer.